# piping ssh to a shell script and not seeing stdin echo

Tags: ssh, pipe, stdin

I have an awk script in `.bashrc` that reads characters and modifies some keywords. It works perfectly when I pipe `tail -f` and other basic commands through it, but I have a problem when I pipe ssh through it. Everything works fine as expected except I cannot see anything I type on terminal until I press return:

```
~# ssh admin@localhost -p 5200 | my-script

admin@localhost's password: 

admin connected from 127.0.0.1 using ssh on home

admin@ssh-server> exit   ***<- I don't see this line (including the prompt) at all on terminal until I type my command (exit) and press Enter***

Connection to localhost closed.
```

I *think* I understand why it's behaving like that but don't know how to fix it. I think the interactive commands to ssh are not sent through pipe until EOL is returned. I have tried everything I found searching from unbuffer/stdbuf to tee/script and playing with various redirection commands but all without luck.

**Note**: I'm actually ok that the strings are passed to my-script after EOL, I just need to be able to see what I'm typing i.e. need terminal stdin to echo as usual.

Comment: it won't echo if you pipe it away. Use a tee to pipe it into the file and then into the script. Or make your script to do that job.

Comment: @Jakuje - I assume you meant 'ssh example.com | tee file | my-script' .... I still see same behavior. Can't see what I'm typing until hit return (no stdin echo by tty kernel).

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do the following:

```
$ ssh user@example.com | tee output
Last login: Tue Aug 15 03:06:11 2017 from 127.1.2.3
$ ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
$ logout
Shared connection to example.com closed.
$ cat output
Last login: Tue Aug 15 03:06:11 2017 from 127.1.2.3
$ ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
$ logout
```

I see the prompt, my input, and everything else when `ssh`ed into the remote host as normal.

Comment: you're teeing to a file named 'output'... that's not what I'm doing. I'm piping to an awk script shown as 'my-script'

Comment: How about `| tee >(my-script)`?

Comment: @AndrásKorn - that works partially. I get duplicate output on terminal, one from ssh and one from my-script. I need the interactive ssh output to be processed by my-script first and then printed on terminal.

Comment: You could try to make stdin and stdout unbuffered using `stdbuf -i0 -o0`, but something your script does may still insist on reading an entire line before outputting anything.

Comment: @AndrásKorn - I had tried stdbuf before without luck. Also I'm totally ok with my script reading an entire line before outputting, the problem is I can't see what is being typed inside ssh session i.e terminal doesn't echo stdin until eol is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If your interactive shell doesn't require a terminal to work, consider disabling PTY in your SSH client, by adding option `-T` to **ssh(1)** command. You will be able to see your typings because the echo is done in your local terminal in this case.

Note that OpenSSH **ssh(1)** redirects stderr to stdout if PTY is enabled, so your script may get less data if PTY is disabled. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838624/why-does-openssh-requesttty-cause-stderr-redirected-to-stdout.